# How to Search a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, search-box

I have a textbox and search button. Currently the Search button doesn't do anything. I do not know how to search in a GridView. I have researched for a few hours and the examples do not work because I use Stored Procedures (one is a select statement that works for this GridView, meanwhile I see I would need some other select to get the search... but I don't see how to incorporate two selects here). How can I add a search to this?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="viewregistrantpaper.aspx.cs" Inherits="viewreg" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<h1>View Registrant</h1>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="formtextbox"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnSearch" runat="server" onclick="BtnSearch_Click" Text="Search" CssClass="formbutton" />


        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrant"  
            CssClass="mGrid"  
    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" >
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>

            <Columns>


                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />


                <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalNumberId" HeaderText="Local" 
                    SortExpression="LocalNumberId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalUnionEmail" HeaderText="Local Email" 
                    SortExpression="LocalUnionEmail" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DistrictId" HeaderText="District" 
                    SortExpression="DistrictId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByFirstName" HeaderText="Completed By First Name" 
                    SortExpression="CompletedByFirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByLastName" HeaderText="Completed By Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="CompletedByLastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompletedByPhone" HeaderText="Completed By Phone" 
                    SortExpression="CompletedByPhone" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" 
                    SortExpression="Position" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" 
                    SortExpression="Email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ShirtSize" HeaderText="Shirt Size" 
                    SortExpression="ShirtSize" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" 
                    SortExpression="Comments" />
            </Columns>

<PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>

        </asp:GridView>
    <div style=" width:100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceViewRegistrant" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Events2 %>" 
            DeleteCommand="spDelRegistrant" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            InsertCommand="spInsRegistrantPaper" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            SelectCommand="spGetRegistrantPaper" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
            UpdateCommand="spUpdateRegistrantPaper" 
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="RegistrantId" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="EventId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalNumber" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalUnionEmail" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DistrictId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByFirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByLastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByPhone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Position" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ShirtSize" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="RegistrantId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalNumber" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LocalUnionEmail" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DistrictId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByFirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByLastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CompletedByPhone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Position" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ShirtSize" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Comments" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
    </p>

</asp:Content>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
 <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtSearch" Name="FirstName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="%%" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
```

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [Events2]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spGetRegistrantPaper]    Script Date: 11/25/2015 11:10:14 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetRegistrantPaper]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FirstName nVarChar (255)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT LocalNumberId,
        LocalUnionEmail,
        DistrictId,
        CompletedByFirstName,
        CompletedByLastName,
        CompletedByPhone,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Position,
        Email,
        ShirtSize,
        Comments
        FROM Registrant
        WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%'

END
```

Comment: So your SP `spGetRegistrantPaper` expect any parameter? Have you implemented the filter in your SP?

Comment: Currently no, it just selects * from the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have have to modify your Stored Procedure `spGetRegistrantPaper` to send filtered records to the web application. You can modify it with a `Where` clause like this (for eg):-

```
SELECT * FROM RegistrantPaper WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @Name + '%'
```

Where, `@Name` will be input parameter in your SP.

Next, add a Select Parameter to your `SQLDataSource` mark-up like this:-

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtSearch" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" 
         Type="String" DefaultValue="%%" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this today and get back to you.

Comment: I just made an edit to my question. I changed my Stored Procedure and added a few lines to my ASP.Net page. Now the GridView disappeared completely from the page.

Comment: Is there a way to have a select statement get all the data for the GridView and then have another select statement for this search that can narrow down the data in the GridView? I'm thinking the issue is I need two statements for the GridView maybe.

Comment: @RockOn - Hey your SP looks good. Yeah you are not able to see the data on initial page load because we have nothing in the textbox. So for that only we had added the `DefaultValue="%%"` which will display all the records on Page Load. I see you did that but I am not sure why you have added ` <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />` remove that.